# Why does a picture appear in the GUI Builder and on the device but not in Codename One Simulator?

Tags: css, codenameone

I am designing my app UI with the GUI Builder. I created a new Form and defined a style as follow :

```
FinishFlagIcon {
background-image: url(pics/FinishFlag.png);
cn1-background-type: cn1-image-scaled-fit;
cn1-source-dpi: 320;
font-size: 11.9mm; 
}
```

I set this style on a label and it appears on the GUI Builder. 
[image: Project in the GUI Builder]

However when I launch the project in the simulator it does not appear anymore. 
[image: Project in the simulator]

I also tried to use a Scaled Label and defined the icon as FinishFlag (which was present in the res file), and again it appeared in the GUI Builder but not in the simulator. Of course there is no error printed in the console telling me the file could not be found.

Please note: the res/myCustomTheme.css folder holds all the subfolders related to the png (and those subfolders are populated with low to hd pngs) and the src/theme.res has the pictures (folowing Shai's advice) :
[image: Project theme.res file with the images]

So what should I do to make the picture appear in the simulator ?

*Edit : I tried to hand code the UI and added a Label (with the UIID defined above) to the the central area of a BorderLayout. I does not appear either until I add **3** spaces or more to the Label. I did not try again with the GUI Builder. It looks odd to me, is it done on purpose ?*

Edit September 13th 2017 : If I build the app and open it on a real Android device then the labels appear.
[image: Project on the device]

Edit September 15th 2017 : For people having the issue of component not showing, as advised in the accepted answer the solution consists in **removing top or bottom constraint of the component not showing and setting it to auto (click on the lock) so that there is enough space for the components**. So eventually after setting to "auto" the bottom constraint of the progress bar an labels the expected result appear on the simulator  :

[image: Layout with fewer constraints on the bottom components]

Any help appreciated,

Comment: If you open the src/myCustomTheme.css file, and look under "Images", do you see the FInishFlag.png image there?

Comment: When I open /src/myCustomTheme.css.res I can see all the images including FinishFlag.png. But if I open /ser/theme.res then the FinishFlag.png file isn't there. However the "working" image IS present in theme.res (maybe I added it manually to the theme.res but I can't remember). I forgot to tell that I used the constant OverlayThemes in theme.res to automatically load myCustomTheme.css after theme.res. Should I remove this constant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images in your issue are a red herring.  It looks like the problem is with your layout insets.  Notice that none of your lower components are showing up in the simulator.  The "progression" label, the three zeroes, etc...

I can't see the constraints you are using for the flags or the zeroes labels, but I can see that the "progression" label has fixed insets on both top and bottom.  This may result in a zero height if there isn't enough space for it. Try changing either the top or bottom insets to "auto" so that they are flexible.

Try changing the simulator to use the desktop theme so that you can resize the window and see how the form looks at different sizes.

You can also easily verify this by overriding the `layoutContainer()` method of the form, and check the height that your flag label is getting:

```
public void layoutContainer() {
   super.layoutContainer();
   System.out.println("finishflag height: "+gui_FinishFlag.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Good fishing ;-)! Indeed with the desktop all components appear. This is the first time I get into this issue (it is also the first time I use the GUI Builder in a project). But why do the components all appear on the real device ? They should not appear if they lack space either on the device or on the simulator, shouldn't they ? Anyway thanks for the great support!

Comment: Setting to auto makes the layout behaves as expected! Thank you @stevehannah!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the "right" solution for this so maybe Steve can interject but this is what's happening.

You have two resource files: `theme` & `theme.css`.

The images in `theme.css` work great for your styles. However, since the loading process loads `theme` and not `theme.css` the simulator is unaware of these images as the `theme` res file doesn't know of them.

The GUI builder is probably scanning all the res files here so it lets you do that which might be a mistake... You have the following options to workaround this:

- Load `theme.css` and discard `theme` - you will need to define the `inheritNativeThemeBool` flag and should no longer use the designer tool if you take that approach
- Use the designer tool to load the images rather than CSS
- Explicitly load the css res file using `Resources.open` and explicitly pass it to the `Form`
- Explicitly load the css res file using `Resources.open` and set it as the global resource file

Comment: Thanks Shai for these explanations and workarounds. I'll go for your last tip since I want something simple and obvious to maintain. I'll keep you both posted when it works.

Comment: But did you see my edit from yesterday ? I can make it appear via handcoding the GUI if I add at least 3 spaces to the label. Is it related to what you explained Shai ?

Comment: I added `css = Resources.openLayered("/myTheme.css");
       UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(css.getTheme(css.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));` and remove the OverlayThemes from theme.res without change. I will rather try to load the images with the designer and tell you if this works.

Comment: Loading the images with the designer did not change anything. It looks like it is a different issue. What strikes me is the need for 3 spaces to make the image appear.

Comment: Both ways (using the OverlayThemes or explicitly opening using Resources.openLayered()) should work.  You may actually be running into issues with the label not showing up at all. Try creating a component in your UI that you know will be rendered.  E.g. a button with a label... once you have verified that it shows up in your UI, try changing the UIID to FinishFlagIcon and see if it shows up.

Comment: addThemeProps will just add the theme layer but the images will still reside in the css theme not in the global theme. You need to separate the notion of resource file (which contains the images) and styling/theming which just references them and discards them

Comment: Thank you Steve and Shai. I added screen captures to make thing clearer, changed the title and removed one or two sentences to focus on my issue. Steve may be right the Labels do not show at all ... in the simulator. **But on the Android 7 device all Labels appear** as in the GUI Builder. So should I start the project from scratch again.

Comment: There are too many questions here so I might be missing some. A blank label will be hidden automatically unless you invoke `setShowEvenIfBlank(true)`. It seems you added the image files to the main resource file manually now. Is there logic to replace the main resource file with something else or explicitly use a specific one? What does the GUI builder get as the resource file?

Comment: Sorry for nesting several questions into one! I append details as soon as I discover them while enquiring on that issue and it brings new questions! There is no logic to replace the main resource file. Only appending myTheme.css. The GUI builder takes both res files I guess since they are both present. Did you see that on the real device everything appears as it should ?

Comment: So this is a problematic point with the GUI builder. We use both to provide you theming options but we should only use one for the images as the generated code just queries one. @stevehannah do you have an idea on how we can improve that experience?

Comment: Thanks Shai. I believe @stevehannah nailed the issue (not enough space). Is it related to what you wrote or is it something different ?

Comment: It's a different thing, he got it